# Error sending emails through form in Django

Tags: python, django

Bit of a rudimentary Django question. I would like to have a form that asks a user for their name and message and then sends this information to an email (more like a contact form).

This is what I have in my views.py:

```
def assignmentSubs(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AssignmentSubs()
    else:
        form = AssignmentSubs(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = 'Assignment submission: {}'.format(form.cleaned_data['assignment'])
            from_email = 'x2x@gmail.com'
            message = 'Hi, Please note that {} has submitted an assignment for the {} section. We will reach out to you with more detail regarding this submission'.format(form.cleaned_data['link'],form.cleaned_data['assignment'])
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email,['xxx@gmail.com','xxx2.des8@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class AssignmentSubs(forms.ModelForm):
    assignment = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-field', 'id':'assignmentname'}), required=True)
    link = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-field'}))
```

and the html with the form

```
<form method="post" action="/" id="form" class="validate">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-field">
            {{form.assignment}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            {{form.link}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for=""></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Assignment" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the css:

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#form {
  max-width: 700px;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-field {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
label, input {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
label {
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}
input {
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

</style>
```

and my urls.py

This is a two fold problem, I cannot see any of the fields from my form and cannot actually send emails through the form

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('about', about, name='about'),
    path('courses', courses, name='courses'),
    path('notyet', notyet, name='notyet'),
    path('faqs',faqs, name='faqs'),
    path('students', students, name='students'),
...
```

Here is the structure of my project

```
templates
  >classroom (folder)
     >students
       htmlfiles
     >teachers
       htmlfiles
   home.html
  >views
    students.py (this is the views.py I am referring to)
```

Comment: code seems fine, is there any error you're receiving?

Comment: @VishalSingh for starters I cannot see any of the fields in my form. I just see the submit assignment button

Comment: what about the rest of the view, did you add the form to the the context?

Comment: try this under `if` block `return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})`

Comment: @VishalSingh I have added that, still cannot see the fields. Added this to my question

Comment: @mattarello please check the code in my question again

Comment: you're adding it in `else` block.

Comment: @VishalSingh still get the same issue if I move it up to the if block

Comment: you would get an error if you do not return HttpResponse from you function. I wonder why your function is not throwing error.

Comment: @VishalSingh maybe this is a dumb question but is there a way to specify the specific form I would like users to interact with in my html? So there is another different form in my views.py and is there any thing I maybe need to add in my urls.py?

Comment: what's the name of your HTML template and where is it located relative to your project?

Comment: I added the form to my home.html template. The location is classroom/home.html. I have replaced form.html with this already, will edit code in question to indicate this @VishalSingh

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your views.
 Your Form seems fine just make sure the `action` attribute of your form points to the correct view.

**Note:** make sure your template i.e `form.html` is present inside templates directory of your current Django app

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def assignmentSubs(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = AssignmentSubs()
        return render(request, "form.html", {"form": form})
    else:
        form = AssignmentSubs(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = "Assignment submission: {}".format(
                form.cleaned_data["assignment"]
            )
            from_email = "x2x@gmail.com"
            message = "Hi, Please note that {} has submitted an assignment for the {} section. We will reach out to you with more detail regarding this submission".format(
                form.cleaned_data["link"], form.cleaned_data["assignment"]
            )
            send_mail(
                subject,
                message,
                from_email,
                ["xxx@gmail.com", "xxx2.des8@gmail.com"],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
        # use redirect in any of the following way
        # return redirect("some-view-name", foo="bar")
        return redirect("/same/valid/url")
```

Comment: do you mind elaborating on what you mean by my action attribute pointing to the right view?

Comment: I mean `<form method="post" action="/" id="form" class="validate">` action attribute should point to a right URL i.e the view you are using to submit this form.

Comment: Ok, so if the view is the class assignmentsSubs would the action attribute point to the specific class or just the url to the views with the class?

Comment: just the URL of that class.

Comment: If I add the url to the view I get a page not found error when I try and submit the form

Comment: include your `urls.py` file and your directory structure in the post.

Comment: I have added my urls.py, the important parts and my directory structure

Comment: for more information refer to this article https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html